# Wordpress Real Cron Job Hostgator

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a WordPress site hosted by Hostgator.

6 month ago I replaced the WordPress cron with a Real Cron Job following hostgator's instructions:

[How to Replace WordPress Cron with a Real Cron Job](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job)

Cronjob:

```
*  *    *   *   *   wget -q -O - http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Now, the cronjob is not working anymore.

I do not receive any email notification.

Where is the problem?

Comment: There is nowhere near enough info to go on here. You should speak with hostgator

Comment: You could add a cron job like `date > $HOME/test.txt` to see if cron is actually running. If no `test.txt` file is created then cron is obviously not running and hostgator has a problem. If the file is created then something with wget is wrong. In that case you should set your e-mail-address for cron and remove the `>/dev/null 2>&1`-part, so you receive an error if there's a problem with wget. In either case: you should probably change the first column to `*/5` so it runs only every 5 minutes instead of every minute.

Comment: what's the interval time between each cron? if you access directly the file it runs?

Comment: 1 hour. Yes, if I access directly the file it runs.

Answer (score 0):

As of 10th June 2016 - following corn job is working fine on my WordPress website on hostgator !!

```
wget —delete-after http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-cron.php
```